# Would Psion and Psywar HD stack for a psicrystal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Title pretty much says it all. Working with a 16 psywar/5 Sanctified Mind.

If I've read things correctly, my psicrystal would currently be level 16.

If I take some levels is psion, would its level continue to grow?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

[SRD > Psionic Races, Classes, Skills, & Spells > Psion > Psicrystal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/psion.htm#psicrystals)

> Psicrystal abilities are based on the owner’s levels in psionic class**es**.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

It explicitly addresses this concern by pluralizing “classes” – your levels in all classes designated “psionic” count towards the psicrystal’s abilities. Moreover, since you have more than 20 HD, you are an epic character, and with more than 20 levels in psionic classes, you use the [epic psicrystal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/psionicClassProgressions.htm#psicrystalsAtEpicLevel) benefits.

Comment: So Sanctified Mind would count towards it too? I had discounted this due to: "You do not, however,
gain any other benefit a character
of that class would have gained"

Comment: @trojax That clause only prevents the ability it's a part of the description of from advancing the psicrystal, but that ability is irrelevant. Sanctified Mind itself is a psionic class, and as such, advances the psicrystal directly, the same as psion and psychic warrior do, not indirectly via boosting another class's effect on the psicrystal, as that ability does with manifesting.

Comment: @trojax That line refers to what you get from your other class (here, psychic warrior) that sanctified mind is progressing, i.e. you don’t get anything else *from that class* aside from improved manifesting (i.e. you don’t get bonus feats for advancing psychic warrior manifesting). But the sanctified mind *itself* is a psionic class, and therefore levels in it count towards your psicrystal’s abilities. That would be true even if you managed to finagle your way into sanctified mind with nothing *to* progress, so it progressed no manifesting.

Comment: @trojax If it helps, think of the Psicrystal Affinity feat as akin to the Obtain Familiar feat from *Complete Arcane*, instead of the Summon Familiar class feature of the sorcerer and wizard. Your psicrystal is not a benefit of any class, it’s the benefit of a feat. That feat just calculates a portion of its benefits using “levels in psionic classes” as a parameter. If it had instead said “Choose a psionic class. Your levels in the chosen psionic class determine the abilities of your psicrystal,” then neither sanctified mind nor psion would work if you chose psychic warrior.

Comment: Is it safe to assume this should overrule the description of the [psicrystal as a  creature](http://dndsrd.net/psionicMonsters.html#psicrystal)? (That is, "A psicrystal’s characteristics depend on its master. Its Hit Dice are equal to its master’s Hit Dice (*counting only levels in psion or wilder*), its hit points are equal to half its master’s, and its saving throw bonuses are the same as its master’s." Emphasis mine.) If so, can this answer address this seeming contradiction?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That.... I mean, it looks to me like Psicrystal Affinity would have primacy here, so I think we *can* ignore that, but man that’s a dumb line. Even when it was *XPH* alone, the psychic warrior should definitely be on the list, and I would rather hope that soulknife would be too...

Comment: O, I *know* it's *extraordinarily* awful. I remember reading Internet brawls over how to resolve the contradiction and felt a small surge of joy when this ancient question popped up as new. I thought, *He's found… **the answer!*** Then I realized it wasn't mentioned, my hopes were dashed, my joy fled, and I cried a single tear. Anyway. I was really hoping you'd nailed it. Get on this! Stat! `;-)`